# That and which usage and difference

Tags: relative-pronouns, which-that

This is an excerpt from a newspaper.

It was this reference to the ICC that India said it could not support.

Why author uses that and not which?

Comment: US and UK usage differ on the usage of 'which' and 'that'. Try searching the web for "which versus that". The Americans have a stricter rule than the British. Please tell us your source. What newspaper is it, from which country and what date?  Please give a link if possible.

Comment: 470 posts with the tag relative pronouns.